# Configuring CheckStyle with SonarQube 5.4

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, static-analysis, checkstyle

As a learner and a beginner to Static Code Analysis Tools.
I have been facing trouble integrating CheckStyle into SonarQube.

I have already installed the plugin into my SonarQube.
I'm sure there is no compatibility conflict as I have **SonarQube 5.4** and **CheckStyle Plugin 2.4**

**Please assist me what to do in order to run analysis with CheckStyle rules only. Keeping in mind I still don't have any specific profile related to checkstyle rules in my quality profile.**

Answer (score 2):

To use Checkstyle rules, you must enable them in the relevant profile. So:

1. create a new profile
2. add the relevant Checkstyle rules to it
3. either set it as your default profile or associate it to your project
4. execute analysis.

Comment: I have learned the same process and even used it in other version of SonarQube i.e SonarQube 4.2 where I just made a new profile and imported an xml file in order to import rules and make them work in an analysis. But this time in the version 5.4 I'm yet unable to make it work. It would be great if you share a link to the xml file that I could test.